# TFS2018 Automated Test Build The file c:\chromedriver.exe does not exist

Tags: selenium, tfs, tfsbuild

I've set up a build on TFS for my test automation suite. It has 3 tasks - a Nuget restore, the solution build and a VSTest task. In my tests I create a new ChromeDriver instance, and I have the Chrome Webdriver Nuget installed on my solution. This works fine locally. However the TFS build is throwing up an error of:

> OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException : The file
>   c:\chromedriver.exe does not exist

I can't work out on why the Nuget restore isn't restoring the chrome webdriver package. All other packages in the job seem to be restoring/working fine, as it's getting to the first step in my SpecFlow feature file, and failing only when I try to spin up an instance of Chrome. Am I missing something with this? Thanks in advance, Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message that you're getting I'm deducing the following:

- on your local machine you have the `chromedriver.exe` binary in your `C:` driver root folder (something that I don't see as a good idea).
- you either added the `chromedriver.exe` binary location to the `PATH` environment variable or you hardcoded in your tests its location

First, make sure that the location is not hardcoded in your tests.

What you can do:

- manual copy on the Agent machines and add the `chromedriver.exe` binary location to the `PATH` env variable (a restart may be required afterwards). Not really recommended in case you have multiple machines. The upgrade may become a painful task depending on the number of Agents.
- Continue using Nuget. You could eventually check the `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release` folder to make sure it's there after restore and build.

From the Chromedriver Nuget package description:

> Install Chrome Driver (Win32, macOS, and Linux64) for Selenium
>   WebDriver into your Unit Test Project.
>         "chromedriver(.exe)" is copied to bin folder from package folder when the build process.
>         NuGet package restoring ready, and no need to commit "chromedriver(.exe)" binary into source code control repository.

You could also check the information from the Microsoft [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=vsts).